# HTML/JS text file output isn't keeping format of my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I save my form output to file with my save button it doesn't have any format at all.
[image: output from form above collects to be saved as a log]

[image: no format on my text file once saved]

When I save my log, the text file doesn't have any format and I would like to fix.

Code below: at the very least I'd like to have the text file show up in this format:

```
  Name Company Time Description of work
  Name Company Time Description of work
  Name Company Time Description of work
  Name Company Time Description of work
  Name Company Time Description of work
  etc...
```

```js
function getValue() {
            var Items = [];
            var td1 = document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML;
            var td2 = document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML;
            var td3 = document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML;
            var td4 = document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML;
            var td5 = document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML;
            Items.push(td1);
            Items.push(td2);
            Items.push(td3);
            Items.push(td4);
            Items.push(td5);
            console.log(Items);
            return Items;
        }

function display()
{
      document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML += document.getElementById("fname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("lname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("sname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("sname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML += document.getElementById("pname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("pname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML += document.getElementById("jname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("jname").value = "";
}
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = getValue();
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
 
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 
    downloadLink.click();
}
 
function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
 
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
 
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script type="text/javascript">

</head>

<body>
<body style="background-color:royalblue;text-align:center"> <img src="C:\Users\smarlow1\Desktop\WIPs\pic.png" style="max-width:600%" alt="COVHLTH"> 
    <h2>DATACENTER CHANGE LOG</h2> 
<table bgcolor="royalblue" border="5" align="center">
<tr> <strong>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Company</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Time In</b></td>
<td><input type="Datetime-local" name="pname" id=sname></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Time Out</b></td>
<td><input type="Datetime-local" name="pname" id=pname></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Description of Work</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="jname" id="jname"></td>
</strong>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
<td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display()"/></button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400px" align="center" table border="5"> 

<tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
<td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Time In</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Time Out</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
</tr>
<tr> <strong>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea1"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea2"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea3"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea4"></div></td>
</strong>
</tr>

<table align="center" border="1">

<tr>
        
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
<tr>
        <td align="bottom right"><button onclick="location.reload()">Clear Log</button></td>
    </tr>
</html>
```

[image: I'd like the output to look like this when I save the file]

Comment: Please put example of your desired result in `.txt` file

Comment: Also your html has some errors. Please put executable snippet

Comment: I have updated the code in a working snippet and at the bottom added an example .txt file with the output I desire. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your `getValue()` function. Because you put your data with `<br>` tag you need to split them the same way.

```js
   function getValue() {
            var Items = "";
            var td1 = document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML.split("<br>");
            var td2 = document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML.split("<br>");
            var td3 = document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML.split("<br>");
            var td4 = document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML.split("<br>");
            var td5 = document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML.split("<br>");

            for (var i = 0; i < td1.length; i++) {
                if (td1[i])
                    Items += td1[i] + " ,";
                if (td2[i])
                    Items += td2[i] + " ,";
                if (td2[i])
                    Items += td2[i] + " ,";
                if (td3[i])
                    Items += td3[i] + " ,";
                if (td4[i])
                    Items += td4[i] + " ";
                Items += "\n";
                
                
            }
            console.log(Items);
            return Items;
        }

        function display() {
            document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML += document.getElementById("fname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("lname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("sname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("sname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML += document.getElementById("pname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("pname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea4").innerHTML += document.getElementById("jname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("jname").value = "";
        }
        function saveTextAsFile() {
            var textToSave = getValue();
            var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], { type: "text/plain" });
            var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
            var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
            downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
            downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
            downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            downloadLink.click();
        }

        function destroyClickedElement(event) {
            document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        }

        function loadFileAsText() {
            var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
                var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
            };
            fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
        }
```

```html
<body style="background-color:royalblue;text-align:center">

    <img src="C:\Users\smarlow1\Desktop\WIPs\pic.png" style="max-width:600%" alt="COVHLTH">
    <h2>DATACENTER CHANGE LOG</h2>
    <table bgcolor="royalblue" border="5" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Company</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Time In</b></td>
            <td><input type="Datetime-local" name="pname" id=sname></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Time Out</b></td>
            <td><input type="Datetime-local" name="pname" id=pname></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Description of Work</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jname" id="jname"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp</td>
            <td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display()" /></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="400px" align="center" table border="5">

        <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
            <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Time In</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Time Out</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="displayarea1"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="displayarea2"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="displayarea3"></div></td>
            <td align="center"><div id="displayarea4"></div></td>
        </tr>

        <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr>

                <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
                <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <tr>
            <td align="bottom right"><button onclick="location.reload()">Clear Log</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to come up with a custom template format, find and replace the value placeholder, and then save the template result to a file. Example

```
<html>
<body>
  <p align='left'>%%_val_001_%%</p>
  <p align='left'>%%_val_002_%%</p> 
</body>
</html>
```